# Generate python type stub for native moduel with docstring

Tags: python, mypy

I am using the python bindings for [lcm](https://github.com/lcm-proj/lcm) (`-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=python3`) and I would like documentation to work in vscode/pylance. The module does have generated documentation that can be seen in `pydoc3`.

`stubgen -p lcm` will successfully create `_lcm.pyi` for `_lcm.so` but it does not include the doc strings.

https://github.com/simon-ritchie/stubdoc looks like it was made to supplement `stubgen`, but it does not support native modules.

Is there currently a way to make a `.pyi` with docstrings from a native (`.so`) library?